# Importing url libraries with python but error with "request"

Tags: python, libraries

I'm testing out some code and am getting a weird error to what should be fairly straightforward. My code is as follows, and is returning:

```
ImportError: No module named request
```

My code is as follows:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = ('Enter- ')
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('href', None))
```

What did I do wrong this time? I know it's in the first line of the code but am really new to libraries and so I'm assuming I messed something really basic up!

Comment: You didn't install request. Use `pip install request` in terminal.

Comment: I tried that, heres what I got! Jons-Mac-mini:pythonpractice jon$ install request
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 file2
       install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
       install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...

Comment: Make sure your Python version is 3.0+.

Comment: @knh190 `requests` != `request`. This is probably a Python 2/3 incompatibility.

Comment: @Selcuk I mistaken it. `urllib.request` only exists in Python 3.0+. For Python 2 you need `urllib2.request`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are running python 2, rather than python 3.

You can validate this by running `which python` in your command line or in code by:

```
import sys
print(sys.version_info)
```